# Salesforce - Pull all deleted cases in Salesforce

Tags: python, salesforce

I am trying to see if we can pull list of all Salesforce cases that have been deleted using their API using python.

The given below query returns back all Salesforce cases created, but I am trying to see how to retrieve all cases that have been deleted.

```
SELECT Id FROM Case
```

I tried doing the below, but it returned no data whereas I know there are deleted cases

```
SELECT Id FROM Case where isDeleted = true
```

Comment: How are you executing the query call?

Answer (score 1):

Queries that include Recycle Bin need to be issued differently. In Apex you need to add "[ALL ROWS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_query_all_rows.htm)"

In SOAP API it's [queryAll](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_queryall.htm) vs normal query call. in REST API it's a different service, also "[queryAll](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_queryall.htm)".

If you're using [simple salesforce](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce) it's supposed to be

```
query = 'SELECT Id FROM Case LIMIT 10'
sf.bulk.Account.query_all(query)
```

If you're using another library - you'll need to check internals, which API it uses and whether it exposed queryAll to you.

(rememeber that records that are purged from recycle bin don't show up in these queries anymore and then your only hope is something like Data Replication API's [getDeleted()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_getdeleted.htm#topic-title))